# Why do fseek & fputc not work in my program?

Tags: c

I am learning to program in C. Please explain why my program doesn't work. What is wrong? The program creates a file, writes a number into this file, and increases this number each time I run this program. The program counts how many times I have opened the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n;
    int c;
    FILE* f = fopen("count_pr.bin", "a+");
    if ((c=fgetc(f)) == EOF)
    {
        n=1;
        fputc(n, f);
    }
    else 
    {
        ++n;
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fputc(n, f);
    }
    printf ("The program was opened: %d\n", n);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "a+" mode, from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)

> append/update: Open a file for update (both for input and output) with all output operations writing data at the end of the file. Repositioning operations (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) affects the next input operations, but output operations move the position back to the end of file. The file is created if it does not exist.

Output operations move the position back to the end of the file. So every write you do will be at the end of the file.

In addition, you need to make changes as suggested by Klas
If you want to overwrite the number each time, you should use r+ mode

> read/update: Open a file for update (both for input and output). The file must exist.

There is still the issue of creating the file if it does not exist, so in that case, if the file cannot be opened in r+ mode, then you can open it in "w" or "w+" mode and only write to it.

I have updated the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int n;
    int c;
    FILE* f = fopen("count_pr.bin", "r+");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        f = fopen("count_pr.bin", "w");
        if (f != NULL)
        {
           n = 1;
           fputc(n, f);
        }
        else
        {
           printf (" File Open Error");
           exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {    
        c=fgetc(f);
        n = c+1;
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fputc(n, f);
    }
    printf ("The program was opened: %d\n", n);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: If I use "w", then the file's contents are discarded each time I run the program according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/?kw=fopen, right?

Comment: You use "w" only if the "r+" has returned NULL. One of the reasons for "r+" returning NULL is if the file does not exist. So we check for that condition. Answer is updated with code.

Comment: `int` will have a maximum value of `32767` for 16 bit compilers and for 32-bit compilers as most are today it has a maximum value of `2147483647`.

Comment: There is a problem. The program will show "1" after 256 times. Only 1 byte (2^8=256) is written each time in this case.  In addition, I need to use _unsigned long_ instead of int.

Comment: The issue is with the `fputc`. This handles only a single character. and so only a single character is written. You can use `fprintf` with %d to write an `int`. Note that you then need to use `fscanf` to read the byte

Comment: I cannot see the edits, you should make the edits in your original post and then comment here. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You read the value into `c`. Then you increase the *uninitialized* variable `n` by one and write `n` to the file. Since `n` is uninitialized you invoke undefined behaviour.

You need to use the value you read:

```
    else 
    {
        n = c + 1;  // Changed line
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fputc(n, f);
    }
```